# Issue with declare friend template class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I have a first class that looks like:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> class A
```

and a second class that looks like:

```
template <typename T1> class B
```

Now I would like to declare that `A<T1, T2>` is always a friend of `B<T1>`. So I tried:

```
// B.h

template <typename T1> class B
{
    template <typename T2> friend class A<T1, T2>;

    public:
    ... 
}
```

But that does not seem to work. What should I do?

Comment: You can't have a templated friend like that, how would `T2` be set when declaring an object of class `B`?

Comment: The language doesn't support such a construct. If you can post the real design problem you are trying to solve, you might get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Given the you have separate files , A.h and B.h and the condition that only `A<T1,T2>` should be a friend of `B<T1>`, then :

```
//B.h
template <typename T>
class B
{
private:
    T x;
public:
    B(T value);
    //note: B<T> befriends A<T,T1>
    template<typename T, typename T1> friend class A;
};
template<typename T>
B<T>::B(T value)
{
    x = value;
}

//A.h
#include "B.h"
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class A
{
public:
    //note B<T1> and A<T1,T2>
    T1 get(B<T1> &b);
};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
T1 A<T1, T2>::get(B<T1>& b)
{
    return b.x;
} 

//test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    B<int> b(3);
    A<int, char> a;
    cout << a.get(b) << endl;  //3

    return 0;
}
//test.2
B<string> b("test");
A<string,double> a;
cout << a.get(b) << endl; //"test"

//test.3 
B<int> b(3);
A<double,int> a;
cout << a.get(b) << endl; //error:
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, possibly because I use different files? (A.h, A.cpp, B.h, B.cpp, main.cpp). Also, even if it worked, it would solve my problem insofar as compiling, but by design I would like that only A<T1, T2> (for any T2) be a friend of B<T1> (and not any A<T3, T2>).

Comment: Thank you for your help, that looks exactly like what I want now. Unfortunately I tried to do the same in my files and I still can't get it to compile, I'm probably stupidly overlooking something. The compiler gives an error at the line "template<typename T, typename T1> friend class A;", it  complains: " declaration of 'class T' "

Comment: are you adding this code to your existing code to modify it? is so, make sure to retain the logic and syntax. Else if this is the same code that you are running in the 3 files, then i'm not sure i can figure out that error. I dont get any error in mine.

Comment: Ok so as a test, I created a test project with exactly what you wrote. And it doesn't compile for me, same error: 
Test/b.h:12: error : declaration of 'class T' (b.h:12 is where the friend declaration is written)

Comment: Oh and the compiler also says: Test/b.h:4: error:  shadows template parm 'class T'

Comment: this is my project. If you dont mind. http://www21.zippyshare.com/v/MVEG72Mr/file.html

Comment: I downloaded and extracted your file, opened a terminal in the directory and did "g++ test.cpp". Is it just that I needed to do? (apologies for my newbiness, I've only been using QtCreator to write code). Anyway, same for me. See here what I get: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B41pJbehW4QbZ1ZKNVFwQmRXQmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry. i realized that with gcc. Works for me with VC++

Comment: Interesting, so it's the gcc compiler that doesn't like it. Not much I can do about that. Oh well, I'll just declare all the specializations as friends, that's disgusting but it will do for now.